# Anyone could explain computeRedLevel(int sz) in Java TreeMap?

Tags: java, data-structures, treemap, red-black-tree

```
private static int computeRedLevel(int sz) {
    int level = 0;
    for (int m = sz - 1; m >= 0; m = m / 2 - 1)
        level++;
    return level;
}
```

I cannot figure out how this algorithm work to compute the Red level? Could somebody explain it?

Comment: What do you mean by "why it could compute the Red level"?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I mean how does this algorithm work.

Comment: @user2916610 Did you read the comment explaining the method in the source code of `TreeMap`? Excerpt: _This level number is computed by finding the number of splits needed to reach the zeroeth node._

Answer (score 0):

As per the implementation the method `computeRedLevel(int size)` is called by `buildTree()` method which assigns all nodes as BLACK. This is the last full' level of the complete binary tree produced by `buildTree()` method.

Now, as `TreeMap` uses `Red Black Tree` and RBT is a `self balancing binary search tree`, to go to the last level from the top it will decrease the size by 2 at every iteration as the height of the self balancing BST is `O(logn)`.

Hence, this will return the last level.

```
for (int m = sz - 1; m >= 0; m = m / 2 - 1)
        level++;
    return level;
```

Answer (score 0):

Description of `computeRedLevel`

> Find the level down to which to assign all nodes BLACK. This is the last `full' level of the complete binary tree produced by buildTree.

First, trace back sz, it is found that sz is the size of the copied map.
Second, TreeMap is backed by **Red-Black Tree(RBT)**, on which the Black Heights are the same.

regarding all elements in copied map as the nodes in an complete binary tree, and coloring all nodes in the perfect part of [complete binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) black, will easily satisfy the feature of RBT.

`computeRedLevel(int sz)` is used to compute the level of perfect binary tree part of complete binary tree.
For example, the level of the perfect part of complete binary tree in below picture is 3. so `compteRedLevel(11)` is 3.
[an complete tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlaNZ.png)